# Are there any batch methods to speed up file creation on Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to create a lot of individual files on Google Drive in one folder. Currently the only way I see it can be done is using folderName.createFile(). Creating files one by one with this command is tediously slow.

Is there a faster way to do it like a batch creation tool from an array of files?

Comment: Why not using a for loop to do it?

Comment: @Kessy Because it'll be slow. Batch methods are faster.

Comment: @mich Try using advanced Google services or drive api directly.

Comment: @TheMaster I never used the API before. I looked at the methods there and I found only a method to create a single file: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

Comment: I didn't say there was a batch method. Just that it'll be a bit faster.

Comment: @TheMaster I suppose I could make a UrlFetchApp.fetchAll( Array of http requests ) so google will process it all at once. Makes sense?

Comment: @michaeldon Yes, that is a possibility. `.fetchAll` makes asynchronous requests, but  drive-api  might rate limit.

Comment: Can I ask you about the mimeType of `files` of `I need to create a lot of individual files on Google Drive in one folder.`? And from `folderName.createFile()`, I cannot understand about your script. Can you provide more sample script for correctly understanding your question?

Comment: @Tanaike The script downloads an entire website and making a static copy, renaming paths into filenames. Since I might encounter any sort of file on the website, I need to be able to save any kind of file. Using folderName.createFile() I can create text files like .js, .css, .html and by downloading a blob and then using setName and folderName.createFile(blob)  I can create any non text file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, how about the following flow? 1. Create new file (text file?) as the empty content using the batch request. 2. Put the data retrieved from URLs to each files. In this case, how about running the script with the asynchronous process? https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll At Google Drive, the process cost for creating new file is higher than that of update. This flow uses this situation. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike using parallel processing is a good idea. I've used web apps for that in the past, but it gets very messy with triggers. I think fetchAll with a web app is a good route.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that is the direction you expect, can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried to understand your code on GitHub but I am not sure it applies to my situation. I tried to boil it down to a basic UrlFetchApp like this:

function call(){
  var file = getFile('/translateTool/thebutcherstation.com/2.html');
  
  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : {file:file}
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx0aIU_XjOHPXh0P6y2dTMmvGpI6WAuac_Cq5BOGw7nDLRlodT-/exec',options)
  Logger.log(response)
}

Which seems to post without error, but I don't know how to work with the file in the web app

Comment: @Tanaike In the web app I added a function doPost(e) {

but whatever I do with 'e' I can't seem to work out what kind of object it is or how to work with it.

I am sure you have a better idea. I'm not very familiar with doGet and doPost.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your current situation. So can you update your question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Have you manage to do it faster with the API? Have you though of creating a feature request on google issue tracker to add this option?

Comment: @kessy I have built a solution. You can see it in the answer to this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tanaike I have built a solution. You can see it in the answer to this question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the latest Google Drive API (v3) supports any 100 actions in a single http call. The default endpoint is `/batch/api_name/api_version`. Most of the Drive client libraries have functions built-in to work with it.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) gives the details, and here is an example in [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#java). Notice how all of the queries, after being constructed, are `queue()`-ed into the batch call, which is executed as a single HTTP connection.

Update from comments: Google Drive API does not currently support batch file upload or download queries. Consider looking into Google Cloud Platform's Storage Buckets (or similar services) for more large-scale file options.

Comment: It doesn't support file creation. Does it though?

Comment: You can batch together any set of API calls and send them to the batch endpoint at once. So in that Java example, rather than `driveService.permissions().create()` you could say `driveService.files().create()` then call `.queue(batch)` on the file create query

Comment: Your linked page says `Currently, Google Drive does not support batch operations for media, either for upload or download.`, which I believe,  would include `files.create`. Still a good answer as this page doesn't seem to be linked directly from guides or reference section.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You may want to reflect your desire to upload in the question, then. `files.create` is not an upload query by default. In most file systems, `upload` and `create` are separate actions; however, Google's `create` does support an upload option. I think it's worth noting that the overhead of establishing an HTTP connection is likely small compared to the overhead of data transfer. Furthermore, what's your use case? Maybe something like Google Cloud Platform Storage Buckets will be more suited to large amounts of files than Google Drive.

Comment: I'm not OP. You should ping @michaeldon

Comment: Lol thanks; didn't notice that. @michaeldon, what's your use case?

Comment: @McKayM you can see in the other thread above, but here it is again:

The script downloads an entire website and makes a static copy, renaming paths into filenames. Since I might encounter any sort of file on the website, I need to be able to save any kind of file. Using folderName.createFile() I can create text files like .js, .css, .html and by downloading a blob and then using setName and folderName.createFile(blob) I can create any non text file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok pleased to confirm **it can be done** with UrlFetchApp.fetchAll().

Here is how I did it. I am not a professional programmer so please forgive my transgressions in the code :) Special thanks to @TheMaster and @Tanaike who put me on the right track.

On the web app you need to apply the following code:

```
//doPost (note I updated the code on stackoverflow after posting my answer as there was an error)
const doPost = e => {
  try{
    var diskPath = getFolder(e.parameter.diskPath)[0];
    const file = diskPath.createFile(e.parameter.fileName,Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(e.parameter.file),e.parameter.contentType));
  }
  catch(e){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(e)
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput( 'Saved:' + 'e.parameter.fileName: '+e.parameter.fileName + 'e.parameter.contentType '+e.parameter.contentType);
}
```

The code must be published as a web app. within the script editor click "Publish" and then "Deploy as a web app" and select "Project version" as "New". "Who has access to the app:" should be set to "Anyone, even anonymous" and then save. You will be given a public URL and you enter that in the script below:

```
//save files function
function saveFiles(fileArr){   //note file blobs must have setName and have contentType set so we save them in the fetch array:  arr = [[file1/Blob2,'image/jpeg',name1],[file2/Blob2,'text/html',name2],............];
  var url = 'INSERT YOUR WEB APP PUBLIC URL HERE'
  var fetchArr = [];
  for (var i in fileArr){
    var file = fileArr[i][0];
    var bytes
    try{                                //if file is already blob prevent error getting Blob
      bytes = file.getBlob().getBytes()
    }
    catch(e){
      bytes =  file.getBytes();
    }
    var fileName = fileArr[i][2];
    var contentType = fileArr[i][1];
    var payload = {
      fileName: fileName,
      contentType : contentType,
      file: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bytes)
    };
    var options = {
      url: url,
      method: "POST",
      payload: payload,
      muteHttpExceptions : true,
    };
  fetchArr.push(options) 
  }  
 
  UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(fetchArr);
}
```

The above code creates a fetch array of URLs with files attached, and then posts them to the web app. The web app then saves them asynchronously saving you a heap of time if you have a lot of files you want to save to disk at once.

In order to run the code you need to call saveFiles(fileArr) from another script which builds the array. The array should have the following format:

[[file or blob, content type, name for the new file as a string],[file or blob, content type, name for the new file as a string],.....]

The content type is a [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) and can be derived from the old file (if you are not making a new Blob) like so: fileName.getContentType(). If you are making a new Blob you should set the contentType according to the MIME type for the file type you are creating.

Edited: Just a note about rate limiting. I hit a rate limit when I tried to save over 13 files in one go, but I was able to send batches of 10 files every few seconds without any problems.

Comment: Do note that if someone was able to figure out the published url, they'd be able to upload to your drive without any restrictions

Comment: @TheMaster this could be circumvented by selecting only myself as "Who has access to the app"

Comment: Yes. But `Urlfetch` needs to be modified accordingly with oauth tokens.